# Erro na instalação do MongoDB

Tags: linux, mongodb, mint

Estou tendo problemas no passo 1:

```
Importe a chave pública usada pelo sistema de gerenciamento de pacotes.
```

Quando eu executo o comando:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp: //keyserver.ubuntu.com: 80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
```

O terminal me responde com:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.XJQ1Kc7e9m/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp: //keyserver.ubuntu.com: 80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
gpg: Note: '--recv' is not considered an option
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
usage: gpg [options] [filename]
```

O que pode estar causando esse erro ?
Versão do linux: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa Cinnamon 64bits

Comment: Veja se ajuda : https://tecadmin.net/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Eu acabei instalando fora do terminal, usando o instalador de pacotes, dessa forma aí tbm nao deu certo